# Ubuntu turned into Kali GNU/linux desktop by Katoolin

Tags: 15.10, katoolin

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 and after few days I installed Katoolin and now it shows Kali GNU/Linux Desktop and my Ubuntu Software Center is not working
even after removing Katoolin. So how to get back to Ubuntu 15.10 without having a fresh installation?

Comment: try 'sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop'

Comment: I recommend backup and reinstall.

Comment: From what you describe, it sounds like system files were replaced. While it's possible to recover from this, it's complicated, usually different for every situation, can break the installation further. It's probably not worth it to try. Since it sounds like you have a functioning OS (mostly), do what @xangua suggested and backup and reinstall.

Comment: same problem here. no idea how to recover. waiting for 16.04 to see if katoolin remnants are removed completely

Comment: somebody  generous, plz offer some bounty here! this is an important question.

Comment: @MycrofD: How did you install it?

Comment: used the katoolin script

Comment: Try to reinstall the Ubuntu using a live CD, but when choosing the partition DO NOT delete the system partition or format it. Keep the `/home` folder if it's there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updated Ubuntu 16.04, now I'm running Kali?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834132/updated-ubuntu-16-04-now-im-running-kali) IMHO the linked page provides better solutions than this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem after installing Kali via Katoolin on Ubuntu 16.04 and it took me some time to figure out a solution. In my case Katoolin changed the settings in the lsb_release file.

I could fix it with running:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

There I had to change the Kali settings, which do not belong there to:

**For 16.04:**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Xenial Xerus"
```

In case you have another distro you need to adapt the names (see Wikipedia e.g.).

In your case:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Wily Werewolf"
```

**For 17.04:**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=zesty 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.04"
```

---

Then, run the following command to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After doing this everything worked fine again for me.

I hope this helps. Sorry, if the explanation is not perfect; it is my first answer here.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps Katoolin change your user specific settings. I would try to create new user so that I will get a fresh Ubuntu home settings. I usually did this if I messed up with my desktop without reinstalling the distro.