# Security errors for Kali Linux repositories when I run "sudo apt update" on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, software-sources

I've been trying to run `sudo apt update` and I get this output that doesn't seem to actually update:

```
Hit:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease

Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
               
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
          
Get:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
        
Err:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It doesn't seem to actually update (unless it is and I just can't see it), and I don't know what's causing the issue.
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with AMD64 build.
Does anyone have a possible theory to what this is, or even a fix?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Kali forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Kali so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) and [Updated Ubuntu 16.04, now I'm running Kali?](https://askubuntu.com/q/834132/)

Comment: @guiverc I'm not running Kali linux, I added a Kali linux repository. I am running Ubuntu 20.04, like I stated in my question

Comment: It is obvious that you have so many Kali Linux sources in your repository, 
remove them and update your apt.

Comment: You maybe were running Ubuntu 20.04, however by adding Kali repositories your system may no longer be a Ubuntu one (`apt` and `dpkg` will always update to the latest packages, and if that's a debian or kali one, your system will change).  I'd suggest checking if via `ubuntu-security-status` how much you've installed, as if you've installed some, you may have a big job removing them, or need to restore backups. If however you've got none, I'd advise removing those entries from your repository lists.  *Your post only shows off-topic repositories, nothing official Ubuntu or from 20.04.1*

Answer (score 0):

I had almost this exact same problem last night. I ran sudo apt-get update and looked for any repositories that I no longer used, removed them, and everything seems to work.

Comment: That seems to be what caused the problem, I removed the oracle-java repo as it was supposedly out-of-date and not working with my version of Ubuntu, so I removed it and now I'm getting this problem

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt autoremove? You can also add the --purge flag to it. This has seemed to fix most of my issues when it comes to repo issues, among other things.

If that doesn't work, then maybe this will:
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6 (edit keys for your need)