# I am unable to install anything including updates!

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

Whenever I try and install anything including system updates I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.16.2-2.1+b1) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
                            Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-x : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-x:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
```

and whenever I run `apt --fix-broken install` this will appear:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.16.2-2.1+b1) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
                            Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-x : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-x:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.16.2) but 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I also can't open any system apps like system setting system updater and most of my other software besides google and terminal and wireshark.

I've run `apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` and I ended up getting this:

```
$ apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:
  Installed: 1.16.2-2.1+b1
  Candidate: 1.18.0-2+b1
  Version table:
     1.18.0-2+b1 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.16.2-2.1+b1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.14.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You haven't provided your release details, but your messages show packages from more than one release (or 3rd party sources), so your issue relates to your release, and likely your sources. We can't help without knowing your OS & release details.

Comment: @guiverc i typed -uname -a and got this HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux     and i typed lsb_release -a and got this lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Please add additional detail to your question, not reply via comment. You are well behind on upgraded packages (using an EOL/unsupported kernel & well behind on security updates etc.  Your sources are polluted; `rmadison` reports `libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 | 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 | bionic-updates/universe` as you'll get in your packages, but you've added something 3rd party of built for a different system that wants 1.16.2-2.1+b1 so someone with `sudo` rights has polluted your sources or added inappropriate packages. Use `apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` to look for details

Comment: You might be on the verge of getting a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). You should not mix Kali/Debian repositories with that of Ubuntu and perform an update. You'll either end up with Kali/Debian ([Updated Ubuntu 16.04, now I'm running Kali?](https://askubuntu.com/q/834132/816190)) or a completely broken operating system stuck in dependency hell. Also see [Proper Installation of Kali linux tools in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/772495/816190) and [How to stop Katoolin from crashing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/895546/816190)

Comment: Looks like you broke your system by including Kali repos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) and [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/124845/)