# How to change Ubuntu server GRUB background image?

Tags: boot, server, grub2, upgrade, katoolin

I installed Katoolin on Ubuntu server. After `apt upgrade` it changes some text and 
images like GRUB background image which is now similar to Kali Linux image. Also, also while booting up it says "kali GNU/linux rolling".

So I have two questions:

1. How to change the background image of GRUB menu?
2. How to change the start up text?

I found [this page on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739476/ubuntu-turned-into-kali-gnu-linux-desktop-by-katoolin) but the tips mentioned there don't work in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Install the grub customizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then open it and select the third panel (appearance settings) scroll down and choose a back ground image.

To uninstall use

```
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove grub-customizer
```

Comment: thank you, but i it does`t work when i run that it says (unable to init server: could not connect: connection refused GTK-WARNING **: 14:21:51:979 cannot open display)

Comment: This won't work as `grub-customizer` requires an xorg desktop session